# Real mouse move event

Tags: javascript, jquery, mousemove

I have a mousemove sensor that scrolls the page in the direction the mouse moves, but even though I don't move the mouse, the event calls itself because the page got scrolling so its like the mouse had moved! I just want to get the real event when the mouse moves, not the page event but the client event.

```
$("body")
.mousemove(function(event){
    if ($("#imgc").css("display")!=="block") {
        var x = Math.round( ((event.clientX - ($(window).width()/2))/($(window).width()/2)*10) *100 )/100

        this.scrollLeft += (x*3);
    }
```

Comment: Hello, can you please provide us with what you have done so far?

Comment: you are going to get negative pnts only :( Provide some brief explanation of what you have done so far etc ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code that calculates which way the mouse has moved, use `screenX` and `screenY` instead of whatever you're currently using. This will give mouse coordinates relative to the screen, so it shouldn't trigger repeatedly if the mouse doesn't actually move.